# Loading css files parallel from IIS

Tags: c#, iis, caching

i have got a problem on an IIS on a  normal PC.

When loading an website from that IIS with more than 20 css and JS,not all files are loaded. I have to reload the page (so that the first CSS and JS are got from cache), and then it  loads the rest.

Any ideas, what could be the reason?
And how i can solve it!

Comment: Are you looking for a mechanism to force an update of a cached Javascript/CSS? If so, have you tried this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ForcingAnUpdateOfACachedJavaScriptFileInIIS.aspx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of possible causes for this, including a slow machine, a slow connection, or very large files.

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) is extremely helpful in helping to narrow down where the bottleneck may be.

In some cases, it is a very large js file, which you can minimize using various tools, including [this one](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/10/16/using-the-new-microsoft-ajax-minifier.aspx) from Microsoft.

If the machine is old or doesn't have much memory, you might consider updating the hardware or moving to a hosted server. The same applies if the connection is slow.